# How to understand the output of quota?

Tags: quota

On a Scientific Linux server (actually a node of a cluster), I run

```
$ quota -vs
Disk quotas for user tim (uid 12345): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
       /dev/vdb      12    126G    126G               3   8389k   8389k
```

1. According to https://www.isg.inf.ethz.ch/HelpHowToCheckQuotaLinux,
   `blocks` is used disk space in kilobytes, but I found that my home
   has used much more than 12 kilobyes:

   ```
   $ du -sh ~
   4.1G    /afs/user/tim
   ```
2. The webpage also says `file` is the number of files, but I have much
   more than 3 files in either my home or the current directory.

So how shall I understand the meaning of the output of `quota`?

Output of `mount`:

```
$ mount

/dev/vda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
/dev/vda2 on /var type ext4 (rw)
/dev/vda5 on /var/lib/cvmfs type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime)
/dev/vdb on /tmp type ext3 (rw,_netdev,usrquota)
sssd on /var/lib/sss/db type tmpfs (rw,size=300M,mode=0700,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:sssd_var_lib_t:s0")
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
AFS on /afs type afs (rw)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/work/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/work/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/work/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
cvmfs2 on /cvmfs/xxx.xxx.xxx type fuse (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/work/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/work/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
cvmfs2 on /cvmfs/xxx.xxx.xxx type fuse (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/work/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/work/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/work/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/xxx/xxx/xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx:/Volumes/RAID/Data/xxx on /afs/user/xxx/xxx type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
xxx.xxx.xxx on /afs/user/xxx type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
cvmfs2 on /cvmfs/xxx.xxx.xxx type fuse (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions)
cvmfs2 on /cvmfs/xxx.xxx.xxx type fuse (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions)
cvmfs2 on /cvmfs/xxx.xxx.xxx type fuse (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions)
cvmfs2 on /cvmfs/xxx.xxx.xxx type fuse (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions)
```

Output of `fs lq`

```
$ fs lq /afs/user/tim
Volume Name                    Quota       Used %Used   Partition
user.tim                   10485760    4266340   41%          0%
```

Comment: Show the output of `mount`.

Comment: I am not sure if it has some private or sensitive information. Can you help to remove any such information after I post it?

Comment: I can certainly look at it. But it would be unusual for that to be sensitive...

Comment: posted.......... the output of `mount` changes every time I runs it, and I don't know why.

Comment: Most likely because different users are logging in and out of the cluster, and their home directories get mounted and unmounted when they do so.

Answer (score 1):

The listed quota applies to the `/dev/vdb` device, which you can see is mounted on `/tmp`. So, you can only create 8 million files or use 126GB of space under `/tmp`.

To see your AFS quota, for your network filesystem, you need to run `fs lq <directory>`.

For example: `fs lq /afs/user/tim`

Comment: Thanks. What are the differences between the purposes of the quota applying to `/dev/vdb` and of the AFS quota?

Comment: @Tim `/tmp` is a filesystem local to that cluster node, while `/afs/user/tim` is an [AFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System) network filesystem which is handled in a completely different manner, and is presumably accessible to all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: is `/tmp` not a permanant storage for my data? Is `/afs/user/tim`?

Comment: Is it possible to make the output of `fs lq` human readable i.e in MB or GB? I posted its output.

Comment: is the quota that applies to the /dev/vdb device just for me or for all the users of the node?

Comment: @Tim `/tmp` is _temporary_ and its contents are usually deleted when the cluster node is rebooted. (Check with your cluster administrator.) Use this for large intermediate datasets your program generates, but not for the final output.

Comment: @Tim And you're asking many questions now, most of which ought to be directed to the cluster administrator.